# HV probe to CRT oscilloscope?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope, multimeter

Can you guys tell me if it's okay to hook up my HV prove to my CRT oscilloscopes? And what about a multimeter, what kind of precautions do I need to take with using that? I read somewhere that it's possible to damage a multimeter this way...
Thanks all.

Comment: There is no generic HV probe or generic multimeter or generic oscilloscope.

Comment: What scope?  What probes?  What multimeter?